# Why do we get undefined references warning in exam class when labels are defined and used in solutions (and answers are not printed)?

Tags: cross-referencing, exam

Let us consider this code which uses the [exam class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam).

```
\documentclass{exam}

%\printanswers

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question Why do we get undefined references warning in this case?
  \begin{solution}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{enu:l}This will not give the answer.
    \item And neither this one. This one~(\ref{enu:l}) did not give
      the answer either.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

The label is being defined and *used* inside the solution. However, it generates
an undefined references warning when the answers are not being printed.

> ```
> LaTeX Warning: Reference `enu:l' on page 1 undefined on input line 12.
> ...............
> ...............
> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
> ```

But common sense dictates that since the label is being defined and used
inside the solution, we should not get the warning message depending on 
whether  the solution is being printed or not.

Or if a phantom output of the solution is being generated to leave space for it,
we should not get the warning. It is being processed, is not it?

Then why do we still get the warning?

A bug perhaps? Or a feature? *(Perhaps not.)*

Comment: When you don't print answers, the labels in the solution are not written in the `.aux` file, but the solution text in main file is read. Hence the warning. Check the `.aux` file with and without `\printanswers` line. Is it a bug? I am not sure.

Comment: @HarishKumar Is not some phantom output being generated in the output to leave the space for answer? And if it is being read (and processed, hence the warning), what is wrong with creating the references?

Comment: From the class file: `If printanswers is true, we print the solution using a TheSolution environment. If printanswers is false and cancelspace is false, we insert lined vertical space equal to the optional argument (the default value of which is 0pt).`

Comment: Or look at the output of your example. Referring to something non-existing? It's a bit odd.

Comment: @Johannes_B I do not get your point. From the package documentation, "... solution, solutionorbox, solutionorlines, solutionordottedlines... Each of these can take one optional argument, which is an amount of space to be left for the students to write their answers when solutions are not being printed (see section 8.4). If
you use these environments without any optional arguments, then they are identical: They print either the solution or nothing at all." The issue I am trying to convey is, when the text is not being printed at all, why complain about references *totally contained* inside it?

Comment: The complain is issued, when `ref` tries to find the label (number/position of the label). But that was never placed, as the content of the environment was sent to nirvana.

Comment: @Johannes_B Now please picture this. 
"Hey, compiler, ignore this `\label`, we are inside solution which is not being printed." Looks like a good command. 
But, "issue complain for this `\ref`, it has not been found". Should not this be as well, "... ignore this `\ref`, we are still inside solution which is not being printed." 
See the contradiction?

Comment: I think i just now realised that *both* are inside a solution env. Sorry. Let me have a look at this.

Comment: It boils down to the following. But i don't have enough experience with the internals to be helpful here. `\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{testme}{%
\setbox\z@\vbox%
\bgroup
}{\egroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{testme}
 test
 \label{masroor}
 \pageref{masroor}
\end{testme}
\end{document}
`

Comment: @Johannes_B I understand your MWE, but only partially. I have even less experience with internals to understand this. But I see that it produces the effect I am trying find the reason for.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18754786#18754786

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redefine `solution` to grab its contents, instead of typesetting it in a box that's discarded.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\RenewEnviron{solution}[1][0pt]{%
  \ifprintanswers
    \Solution@Emphasis\begin{TheSolution}\BODY\end{TheSolution}
  \else
    \ifcancelspace
    \else
      \par\penalty\z@\vspace*{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\printanswers

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question Why do we get undefined references warning in this case?
  \begin{solution}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{enu:l}This will not give the answer.
    \item And neither this one. This one~(\ref{enu:l}) did not give
      the answer either.
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{solution}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\RenewEnviron` or `\renewenvironment`?

Comment: @Masroor `\RenewEnviron`, because we want it to become an environment grabbing its contents.

Comment: But `\RenewEnviron` does not work in my machine, but `\renewenvironment` does. Are we talking about different version of LaTeX?

Comment: Also, it does complain about `\BODY` when `\printanswers` is on.

Comment: @Masroor You probably have an outdated version of `environ`. Please, upgrade your TeX distribution. You *can't* use `\renewenvironment` for this job.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, an old version of `environ`. (And if you are wondering why I accepted the answer rather prematurely, I did that because it was from egreg. :-)) Anyway, things are fine now. Though this solution is somewhat shaky when there is lstlisting code inside the solution. But I have found a way to circumvent that issue.

Comment: @egreg So I still get these warnings with exam version 2.603 2017-12-17 (your solution worked btw). Is this a bug? Should it be reported?

Comment: @vagoberto Apparently the author of `exam` doesn't know about this.