# How to suppress undefined references in exercise answers when using answerdelayed option?

Tags: cross-referencing, warnings, exercises, undefined

I'm using the exercise package to write exercises and their corresponding answers. Each chapter contains a list of exercises at the end of the chapter, and I want all answers of all exercises are to be included included at the end of my course. To do this, I'm using the package option answerdelayed and this works well, aside from annoying issue. The problem is that any references defined in an answer are reported as undefined even when the only reference to them is also in the answer.

For example

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[answerdelayed]{exercise}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Exercise}
        \label{exe:some_exercise}
        \blindtext
    \end{Exercise}
    \begin{Answer}[ref={exe:some_exercise}]
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{MWE figure}
            \label{fig:some_figure}
        \end{figure}
        \blindtext as shown in Figure~\ref{fig:some_figure}.
    \end{Answer}
\shipoutAnswer
\end{document}
```

reports

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:some_figure' on page 1 undefined on input line 20
```

If I drop the option `answerdelayed`, I get the answer with correct reference to the figure, but that gives me ugly long list of questions and answers. How can I suppress the undefined reference warnings caused by the exercise answers which are not being included? I've tried the workaround suggested in a related post ([How to suppress undefined references in exercise answers when using noanswer option?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551646/how-to-suppress-undefined-references-in-exercise-answers-when-using-noanswer-opt?newreg=b7e95c2e84c24dc598a63e6df38d2fba)), but that doesn't work for the `answerdelayed` option it seems.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem by compiling your MWE on my system. I get errors about undefined references only during the very first compilation while .aux-files containing cross-referencing-information do not yet exist. This very first compilation also delivers to console the message `LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.`. If I do so without deleting aux-files between compilations everything matches out correctly. If on your platform things are different we can compare package-versions etc as noted in the .log-file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the other question uses a bit complex syntax. This can be done more easily using the `etoolbox` package, which (among other things) provides a command `\AtBeginEnvironment` that adds code to the start of an environment.

Adding code at the start of an environment means that the code has scope only inside of the environment, so `\ref` still works outside of answers.

The redefinition can be enclosed in a check for the `answerdelayed` or `noanswer` option to make `\ref` work in normally in answers when neither of these two options are used.

The redefinition below includes a check if the reference is defined, using `\IfRefUndefinedExpandable` from the `refcount` package. Using this check `\ref` can be used normally during `\shipoutAnswer`, while the undefined reference warning is suppressed when `\shipoutAnswer` does not occur in the document. To use the original definition of `\ref` in the redefinition, `\let\origref\ref` can be used to copy the original definition to a new macro `\origref` that can be used in the new version of `\ref`.

A disadvantage of this approach is that when a reference in an answer is actually undefined the warning is also suppressed. To make it easier to spot these references you can print a prominent warning in the document itself.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[answerdelayed]{exercise}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\let\origref\ref
\if@AnswerDelay\AtBeginEnvironment{Answer}{%
\def\ref#1{%
\IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{\textcolor{red}{UNDEFINED \detokenize{#1}}}{\origref{#1}}}%
}%
\fi
\if@AnswerOutput\else
\AtBeginEnvironment{Answer}{%
\def\ref#1{%
\IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{\textcolor{red}{UNDEFINED \detokenize{#1}}}{\origref{#1}}}%
}%
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{Exercise}
        \label{exe:some_exercise}
        \blindtext
    \end{Exercise}
    \begin{Answer}[ref={exe:some_exercise}]
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{MWE figure}
            \label{fig:some_figure}
        \end{figure}
        \blindtext as shown in Figure~\ref{fig:some_figure} and Table~\ref{tab:some_table}.
    \end{Answer}
\shipoutAnswer
Solve exercise \ref{exe:some_exercise}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this using the MWE, but still the reference in the answer to the figure in the answer is undefined after uncommenting the `\shipoutAnswer`.  I'm compiling with PDFLaTeX, but other compilers give the same result.

Comment: @JMBaetens in that case indeed the reference is printed as `?` (without the warning). Let me see if that can be fixed easily.

Comment: @JMBaetens I extended the redefinition of `\ref` to make sure it works both with and without `\shipoutAnswer`.

Comment: De MWE is working now! Thanks for sorting this out because I'm not so familiar with low-lavel TeX-code. There's still a major problem though: I have a separate Tex-file per chapter that I include using `\include{chapter_x}`. Now, if you include the code from the mwe from `\begin{exercise}` up to `\end{answer}` in such a file and then call it using `include{chapter_x}`, the workaround doesn't work anymore and you get the 'UNDEFINED...'. If I then check chapter_x.aux, it indeed doesn't contain the figure label. I guess this requires a minor change in the workaround, but I'm not sure how.